# how do i force Flutter to run all the lines inside the function?

Tags: flutter

I have a this function that I need to run during initstate() in its entirety before building the widget. I have used this kind of code before in some parts of my app and it works there, but in this case, flutter jumps out before executing `.then` , goes to build the widget tree, and then returns back to the function but skips the remaining lines. I'm confused where I should properly put async-awaits to force it to finish the block. Also, can I ask where I can read an explanation of the proper flow of execution for flutter so that I can understand it more?

```
Future <bool> checkVendorStatus (buyerId) async {


var _result;

var  vendorDocRef = await buyersInfoColl.doc(buyerId)
    .collection("vendorsCalled")
    .doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
    .get()
    .then((value) async {
        return await value.exists ? _result = true : _result = false;
    }

);
return _result;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`await` is meant to interrupt the process flow until the async method has finished. `then` however does not interrupt the process flow (meaning the next instructions will be executed) but enables you to run code when the async method is finished.

you can write your code like this-

```
Future <bool> checkVendorStatus (buyerId) async {


var _result;

var  vendorDocRef = await buyersInfoColl.doc(buyerId)
.collection("vendorsCalled")
.doc(auth.currentUser!.uid)
.get();
    
 vendorDocRef.exists ? _result = true : _result = false;



return _result;
}
```

Comment: it worked, however I noticed it would still skip the ternary operator even if I put a breakpoint in that line. it still would jump out of the function to build some parts of the tree and jump right to `return _result` I don't understandy why

Comment: how you use this function in your widget please provide a full code also update your question what is your actual problem you're facing?

Comment: Thanks. this is just a function I use to evaluate a change in text on a button before that button gets built in a Dialog widget. It works fine,  its just that I am new to flutter and don't know the flow of execution very well. It seems to be returning the correct result, I just don't expect it what I am seeing when in debug mode. I will mark this correct.